# POST Streaming Audio over HTTP/2 in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, audio-streaming, okhttp

Some background:

I am trying to develop a voice-related feature on the android app where a user can search using voice and the server sends intermediate results while user is speaking (which in turn updates the UI) and the final result when the query is complete. Since the server accepts only HTTP/2 single socket connection and Android HTTPUrlConnection [doesn't support](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/master/android/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpsHandler.java#76) HTTP/2 yet, I am using Retrofit2.

I have looked at [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1217), [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063#issuecomment-152465826) and [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/853) but each example has fixed length data or the size can be determined beforehand... which is not the case for audio search.

Here's what my method for POST looks like:

```
  public interface Service{
    @Streaming
    @Multipart
    @POST("/api/1.0/voice/audio")
    Call<ResponseBody> post(
            @Part("configuration") RequestBody configuration,
            @Part ("audio") RequestBody audio);
}
```

The method sends configuration file(containing audio parameters - JSON structure) and streaming audio in the following manner. (Expected POST request)

```
Content-Type = multipart/form-data;boundary=----------------------------41464684449247792368259
//HEADERS
----------------------------414646844492477923682591
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="configuration"
//JSON data structure with different audio parameters.
----------------------------414646844492477923682591
Content-Type: audio/wav; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"
<audio_data>
----------------------------414646844492477923682591--
```

Not really sure about how to send streaming(!!) `<audio_data>` . I tried using Okio to create multipart for audio in this way (From: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#post-streaming)

```
public RequestBody createPartForAudio(final byte[] samples){
        RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return MediaType.parse("audio/wav; charset=utf-8");
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                //Source source = null;
                sink.write(samples);        

            }
        };

        return requestBody;
    }
```

This didn't work of course. Is this a right way to keep on writing audio samples to ResponseBody? Where exactly should I call `Service.post(config, audio)` method so that I don't end up posting configuration file every time there is something in the audio buffer.

Also, since I have to keep on sending streaming audio, how can I keep the same POST connection open and not close it until user has stopped speaking?

I am basically new to OkHttp and Okio. If I have missed anything or part of the code is not clear please let me know and I'll upload that snippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use a [Pipe](http://square.github.io/okio/1.x/okio/okio/Pipe.html) to produce data from your audio thread and consume it on your networking thread.

From a [newly-created OkHttp recipe](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/2d37490174c29a20dd49ddf4d55d4f995c545504/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostStreamingWithPipe.java):

```
/**
 * This request body makes it possible for another
 * thread to stream data to the uploading request.
 * This is potentially useful for posting live event
 * streams like video capture. Callers should write
 * to {@code sink()} and close it to complete the post.
 */
static final class PipeBody extends RequestBody {
  private final Pipe pipe = new Pipe(8192);
  private final BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(pipe.sink());

  public BufferedSink sink() {
    return sink;
  }

  @Override public MediaType contentType() {
    ...
  }

  @Override public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
    sink.writeAll(pipe.source());
  }
}
```

This approach will work best if your data can be written as a continuous stream. If it can’t, you might be better off doing something similar with a `BlockingQueue<byte[]>` or similar.

Comment: So basically solving it in a producer-consumer way? Can it be done using okio? How can I append the audio data to `@Part ("audio") RequestBody audio` with using just one POST?

Comment: The Pipe class should help. Run the sample to see what the control flow looks like.

Comment: Had sync issues with Pipe. For now, it's working with BlockingQueue<byte[]> .